# What were all the fighters in previous Age of Heroes?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, comic-adaptation, justice-league

In *Justice League*, we got to know that Steppenwolf already tried his plan in the past; and the combined power of Amazons, Atlanteans and humans defeated them. But there were others involved too, some major DC characters, one Green Lantern (not sure which one), Zeus and someone with fire arrows and a few more.

So who were these heroes with powers? Are they some DC comics characters? I can identify Zeus but not the rest.

> Who was the Green Lantern, that died, in that fight?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know that we saw enough of the Green Lantern to know who he was; I'm pretty sure he was not human. I don't see anyone listed in the credits (so the Lantern was probably entirely CGI), so that's no help either. I suspect it was just a nameless Lantern from thousands of years ago.

The other powered characters in that scene were the various "old gods". At least three of them are credited. Besides Zeus, we also see Ares (same actor as *Wonder Woman*) and Artemis (who is probably the bow wielder you're thinking of, if I had to guess.) In the DC universe, there are a dozen or so Olympian gods, all of which would likely have been present.

---

I will point out that Steppenwolf uses the phrase "old gods" to describe Wonder Woman's heritage, but in a way that's generally *not* the same as it's used in the DC comics universe. Zeus, Ares, etc. in the comics are the gods of Olympus, and would be classified as "New Gods" in the same vein as Darkseid. Steppenwolf appears to use the term just to describe the gods of the old world, not referring to the beings actually called the "Old Gods".

Comment: I've seen articles that there were **two** Green Lanterns but the clip is so brief it's possible that it's the same Lantern shown separately. I agree though, the killed Lantern was **not** human. GL Corps set-up?

Comment: maybe. I'm going to see it again, I'll try to pay attention.

Comment: I just watched some bad cam videos about it and there are two lanterns and even wikipedia confirm it too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_in_other_media#Justice_League_.282017.29